# Each child in an array or iterator should have unique key prop reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Hi i get the warning "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop" when i map through an array of objects.

What i am trying to do?
I have an array of objects variable named items and i loop through each item to display its name. Currently in do so i get the above mentioned warning. It works however i want to get rid off the warning.

Sample data named "items" array of objects.

```
items = [{
             children: [{meshes:[10,11], name: 'item_1', index:1},
                        {meshes:[1,2], name: 'item_4', inde:4},],
             index: 0,
             default_name: items,}]
```

Below is the code,

```
function Items(props) {
return (
    <ul className="items_list">
        <div className="itemss">
            {props.items.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <Item
                        item={item}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </div>
    </ul>
);
```

}

What i have tried?
I understand that on mapping each item we should provide unique key property.
so i added index to .map method as below,
    {props.items.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        
                    );
                })}

But this doesn't work...on clicking the back button it would stay in same page.

So could someone help me understand where i am going wrong. Or provide an answer to this. Thanks.

Comment: The unique property need to have the name 'key', changing 'index' to 'key' should fix this for you

Answer (score 0):

You will get this warning only when two or more items in the list have been supplied with the same key, try this change.

```
{props.items.map((item,index) => {
                console.log(index);
                return (
                    <Item
                        key={index}
                        item={item}
                    />
                );
            })}
```

> **Anti pattern**

You should not be using **index** of the **map** for you Key, its an antipattern, it may lead to unpredictable results.

**Please check this:** 
https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

You should be using proper **unique-id** for your Key, like a DB id or some unique-id.

This **Key** is used internally to identify the **DOM elements** to render and not to render again.

Comment: thanks for the reply. true when i log the index it starts from 0..however, it doesnot allow to get back to previous page.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove index from items and add it to your iterator

```
function Items(props) {
return (
    <ul className="items_list">
        <div className="itemss">
            {props.items.map((item, index) => (
                    <Item
                        key={index}
                        item={item}
                    />
                );
            )}
        </div>
    </ul>
);
```